# Darker short-story anthology featuring Whelan-like art, beach campfire on cover?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This one's somewhat vague, and I apologize: I’m trying to remember a hard-cover anthology of Grimm-like tales, a bit more ‘grown-up’ than popular views of Grimm; and, it featured what I remember as the art of Michael Whelan, or someone of similar style, on the covers and for each story.

The cover I believe had a party of adventurers camping on a shore around a campfire.
I had it from the Sci-Fi Book Club in the late-80s/early-90s.  It wasn't very thick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This certainly sounds like the book. Check out *[Once Upon a Time: a Treasury of Modern Fairy Tales](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008PI2778)*, edited by Lester del Rey and Risa Kessler. The cover is by Michael Pangrazio and has three people dressed in vaguely Renaissance-style clothing sitting around a fire on a beach. Pangrazio also did interior illustrations.

The stories are by Isaac Asimov, Terry Brooks, C.J. Cherryh, Lester del Rey, Susan Dexter, Wayland Drew, Barbara Hambly, Katherine Kurtz, Anne McCaffrey, and Lawrence Watt-Evans.

Comment: That's the cover that I remember.  Good job

Comment: Incidentally, can I down-vote myself for framing my question so horribly?  I was an inch away from nixing it :P

Comment: Hey, it was enough information for me to remember it! I wouldn't have remembered the stories, or put it together with the theme without the cover information.